# Parse PFQueryTableViewController loadNextPage() reload tableView issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am using the PFQueryTableViewController, and i am trying to achieve auto loading as the user gets to the bottom of the current page of results (paginating). Everything is querying and displaying as it should.

The issue is when calling `loadNextPage()` as the user scrolls to the bottom. When `loadNextPage()` is called, it also refreshes the tableView, sending the feed to the top and losing your place in the feed. It is correctly adding the next set of posts in the feed. I would like it to work like instagrams feed, where it lands seamlessly in the background and doesn't reload the entire table every time a new page of data is loaded and added to the feed.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by loading next page sooner. I was loading the next page as the user approached the bottom of the screen. I tripled this value and it works much better.